# Midi driven animation in blender 2.6

Tags: scripting, animation

I am looking around for a script that will allow me to trigger animation based on a file input. I'm using blender 2.67b, all the scripts I have seen are for 2.49.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it might help to include links to the old scripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### MIDI to IPO/Drivers

possibly: https://github.com/kwnetzwelt/midi_to_ipo (for blender 2.5 onwards)

It imports MIDI (per track) and converts it to IPO/drivers and comes with a well written *getting started.rtf* document.

Comment: Yes this is very good, it is a bit simple though, you can only map animation to one object position. So I will need to work a little more to create many midi files... Anyway, it's working.

Comment: I'm trying to install this into Blender,but it's not showing up. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be doing alright, but you might look at https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=houdini+midi+control, Houdini I guess uses the old Chops prog. -or maybe it's just their nomenclature. http://digitalcinemaarts.com/docs/houdini/Channels.fmk.pdf

Comment: This response can be made more useful if you elaborate on why you consider these links to be of benefit to a blender user. Your response is more suitable as a comment to the original question instead of an answer because it doesn't yet answer a question